# Adding a value to a prototype object in backbone not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In backbone I have a view with a custom prototype object called "mistakes_dict". I want to keep a tally of the mistakes made, so I want the mistakes_dict to persevere. However I am getting an error when the "next_stage" method runs that mistakes_dict is not defined. Why is this happening? When I define the mistakes dict locally in the nexstage method it works fine but of course then the same dictionary isn't available the next time the method runs.

As a side note how do I make the dictionary create a new key if it doesn't already exist (with a value of 1) and increment it by 1 if it does exists? I know how to do this in Python but I am new to JS.

```
window.View = Backbone.View.extend({

    mistakes_dict: {},

    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },

    events: {
        "click .nextstage"   : "nextstage"
    },

    nextstage: function () {
      var mistakes_string = $("span.highlighted").text();
      for(var i = 0, len = mistakes_string.length; i < len; i++){
        mistakes_dict[mistakes_string[i]] = 1;
      };

    },

    render: function () {
      this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you define inside `window.View = Backbone.View.extend({ ... })` are attached to the prototype so you have to access them through `this`:

```
for(var i = 0, len = mistakes_string.length; i < len; i++){
    this.mistakes_dict[mistakes_string[i]] = 1;
}
```

Of course, since `mistakes_dict` is actually attached to the view prototype, you'll have a single `mistakes_dict` object shared amongst all instances of your `View`; you can think of properties on the prototype as sort of class properties. If you want a distinct `mistakes_dict` on each instance then assign it in the constructor:

```
window.View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.mistakes_dict = { };
        this.render();
    },
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

**mistakes_dict**  is defined directly on the view.

So you need to use `this` context to access it

```
mistakes_dict[mistakes_string[i]] = 1;
```

supposed to be

```
this.mistakes_dict[mistakes_string[i]] = 1;
```